# Problem when using cases environment in pgfplots legend

Tags: pgfplots, boxes, cases, legend, border

I noticed that if I use cases from package `amsmath` in a `pgfplots` legend, the legend box  does not contain the whole text. See the MWE.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [legend entries = {$f(x)=\begin{cases}\exp(x)&x\leq0\\e^x&x>0 \end{cases}$}]
      \addplot[color=red]{exp(x)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Simple example of the box not containing all legend text when using cases in pgfplots]

Also the red line in the legend does not align with the f(x).

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is addressed  in the section 4.8.9 of `pgfplot` manual, *Legends with Customized Texts or Multiple Lines*. You could use the option `text depth` of `\addlengendentry`:

```tex
\addlegendentry[text depth=\baselineskip]
  {$f(x)=\begin{cases}\exp(x)&x\leq0\\e^x&x>0 \end{cases}$}
```

Full example:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot[color=red]{exp(x)};
      \addlegendentry[text depth=\baselineskip]
      {$f(x)=\begin{cases}\exp(x)&x\leq0\\e^x&x>0 \end{cases}$}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: with option text depthenter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the text is moved around. A simple (visual) fix is to raise the box; with trial and error, it seems that 2.5ex is the right amount.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    legend entries = \raisebox{2.5ex}{$f(x)=\begin{cases}\exp(x)&x\leq0\\e^x&x>0 \end{cases}$}
  ]
  \addplot[color=red]{exp(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]